# os.walk() question - how to include subdirectories that Windows File Properties incorrectly lists as "0 bytes"

Tags: python, windows-10, os.walk

This pertains to a Windows 10 machine.  For work I've written multiple Python scripts that utilize the `os.walk()` method for recursively walking through an entire target directory (to include subdirectories) for the purpose of identifying every single file contained within.

During script testing I noticed that one of the subdirectories inside my target parent folder was completely ignored by my script after execution.  Upon inspection of the subdirectory in question, I noticed that Windows File Properties (right click > Properties > General tab) reports the suspicious folder as containing "0 bytes", despite the fact that data is stored inside.

I don't know why File Properties reports this error in the first place, but I **do** know that File Properties is generally an unreliable tool for determining the accurate number of files/total data in a given directory (which is why I wrote this script in the first place, as a substitute for that weakness).

Anyway, I suspect that `os.walk()` is checking this false metadata as a basis to decide whether it should walk the subdirectory and thus it ignores the folder when it sees "0 bytes".  Does anyone know if there's a way to force `os.walk()` to search these types of subdirectories?

Comment: You have said what the type _is_ of these subdirectories — and no one can answer your question without know that…

Comment: `os.walk` makes no value judgments on the files and folders.  What do you see when you `dir` the parent from a command line?  Is it possibly a junction point or symlink?

Comment: Are the folders that are being missed getting included in the `files` value yielded by `os.walk`? That would lend weight to Tim's theory that they're not normal folders but some other strange kind of filesystem thing.

Comment: The files contained within the subfolder are multiple ".bin" segments that make up a raw forensic image.  I'm not at work at the moment so I can't double check but I'm 99% sure that the folder is NOT a symbolic link.  Usually Windows displays an obvious indicator on the thumbnail image of the folder if it is a symbolic link.  I modified my program to print each file path yielded by "os.walk" as it iterates through the target directory, and the subfolder in question is NOT included in the list of printed file paths.